# Free languages courses

Tags: resource-request, online-learning

Where or how can I find free language courses? I do not mean just duolingo or some other app, but proper (online) classes with a teacher, homework, etc. It might sound surprising, but it is actually quite common for "smaller" languages or countries that are investing money in making their culture and language more widespread. For instance, the Indonesian embassy in Spain organized a free indonesian course last year, which was pretty cool, and I've seen similar things for Welsh, Euskara or Maori (the last one only for people living there or about to move there). All of these cases are just courses that I stumbled upon just randomly. Could someone provide a list or a resource to find such opportunities?

Answer (score 2):

[Coursera](https://www.coursera.org/browse/language-learning) has a bunch of free-to-audit language courses.

I took the [Chinese HSK6](https://www.coursera.org/learn/chinese-for-hsk-6) course a while back.  It was okay, but only covered a minuscule fraction of what a student needs for the HSK6.  It focused on the HSK6 exam, and not on the Chinese language.

There was "homework" where you submit your writing, and your homework is marked by other students.  I found students were very lenient when marking because a lot of the time you're marking something way above your level.  Sometimes I'd leave actual feedback, but most people didn't.